# Login via domain -> how to use "Run As Administrator" feature?

Tags: windows-7

We use domain authentication to login to our Windows 7 PCs (eg: xyz\joeBlog). I typically run as a limited account, but I find myself having to do a fair amount of stuff requiring admin-level privileges.

Typically, I can use the "runas" command, or shift-"Run as Different User".

This does not work for everything, e.g, copy files into a restricted folder, where one is not given the option of "Different User", but merely "Administrator".

Now, how do I allow myself to use the "Run As Admin" feature, since there isn't any account information under the "Local User" control panel snap.

Comment: Post screenshots of the dialog box

Answer (score 1):

If you have UAC setup on your machine, make sure the elevated prompt is not disabled.

It would be under group policy/ Compupter config/Windows/Local/Security/Elevated prompt for standard user.

Also check the Group Policy preferences for the HideRunAsVerb registry key. It would be under [HKLM or HKCU]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer. Set it to zero would enable it.

And of course, make sure UAC is enabled.